# How long does it take for an office add in to be available in the store after being accepted?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-store

My Excel add in got accepted a couple of weeks ago but im still not able to see it in the add in store. How long does it take? I don't know if there is some mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a submission passes validation, and was not submitted with a start date in the future, the app/add-in should be visible within 24 hours. If the submission had a start date in the future, then it will become visible on that date

Comment: My add in has already passed validation. That was about 2 weeks ago but I'm still not able to see it in the store. Does it normally take this long?

Comment: No, this would be unusual. If you share your add-in title, I can investigate further.

Comment: app Name: ServiControl appID: 42949682554

Comment: v1.0.0.1 is available on [AppSource](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381885) since it was approved on November 13th.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking for it in the store inside Excel and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The Validation team reviews your submission.

This can take 3-5 working days, depending on the volume of submissions in the queue.

For more information, please review the following link:

[Make your solutions available in AppSource and within Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-the-office-store)